# Formating\ parsing string before sending in to process argument

Tags: c#, string, replace, process, split

is there a way to remove the \ character before a sub string so there is a quotation marks present without it as in "some text ", it gets displayed when printing it out to console OK but it does when passing it in as a process argument and looks like \" some text\"

example:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.Append("-i some//directory//on//pc//");
builder.Append("somevariables which include white spaces including : // @ chars");
builder.Append("\"this\\is\\another\\directory\\but\\in\\quotation\\marks at the begining\\");
builder.Append("some string variable with an extension such as .mp3 and then end quotation marks\"");
string commandLineArgToAProcess = builder.ToString(); 

process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("some\\die\\program.exe",
                        commandLineArgToAProcess);  

process.StartInfo = info;
process.Start();
```

not sure how to remove the \ before the start and end of the quotation marks which does not appear when printing out to console but it does it included when passing in the argument to the process.

tried also using regex.replace but threw exception
also tried splitting the string but realised each time the string length would be different and there may be a better way
it is all ok when using stringbuilder but as i have to convert it to .ToString() for the process parameter it adds the backslash in again
anyway to get around this will be appreciated 
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried   System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape ?

Comment: i still don't understand why you need remove it.

Comment: i will try the regex.unescape thanks, i need to remove it as it is a set of commands which is decoded by another (third party) program after sending it in as command line args and it wont work if the string is like "\"dircectory/save.mp3\"

Comment: in C# code it is like that **literally**, but when compiled it is not like that.

Answer (score 0):

The backslash is needed to mask the quotation mark. Otherwise it would be interpreted as the end of the string. This is also the reason why there are allways two backslashes, int the fictional paths you are printing. The first one masks the second one. If there weren't two the backslash would be interpreted together with the following sign. For example \n would be a new line.

You can put an @ in front of the string to disable the masking. But this won't work for the quotation mark.